# Tagging the differencies in both files

Tags: linux, perl, bash, text

I know that comparing 2 files is a typical problem and there are many discussions on this problem. but I have a rather different problem while working with text files:
I have two text files which may differ in number of lines. now I want to compare two files and find the lines which differ. after that I want to tag all the differencies in both of files. for example here are the content of my files:

File1.txt:

```
This is the first line.
This line is just appeared in File1.txt.
you can see this line in both files.
this line is also appeared in both files.
this line and,
this one are mereged in File2.txt.
```

File2.txt:

```
This is the first line.
you can see this line in both files.
this line is also appeared in both files.
this line and, this one are mereged in File2.txt.
```

After processing I want both files to be like this:

File1.txt:

```
This is the first line.
<Diff>This line is just appeared in File1.txt.</Diff>
you can see this line in both files.
this line is also appeared in both files.
<Diff>this line and,</Diff>
<Diff>this one are merged in File2.txt.</Diff>
```

File2.txt:

```
This is the first line.
<Diff></Diff>
you can see this line in both files.
this line is also appeared in both files.
<Diff>this line and, this one are mereged in File2.txt.</Diff>
<Diff></Diff>
```

How can I do this? I know that some tools such as **diff** could help me, but how can I convert their results in this format?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Algorithm::Diff. Here's an example which produces output almost like you wanted, maybe you can tweak it to get your exact desired output:

```perl
use Algorithm::Diff;
my $diff = Algorithm::Diff->new( \@seq1, \@seq2 );

my @out1;
my @out2;

while(  $diff->Next()  ) {
    if ($diff->Same) {
        push @out1, $diff->Items(1);
        push @out2, $diff->Items(2);
    }
    elsif (not $diff->Items(2) ) {
        for ($diff->Items(1)) {
            chomp;
            push @out1, "<Diff>$_</Diff>\n";
        }
        push @out2, "<Diff></Diff>\n";
    }
    elsif (not $diff->Items(1)) {
        for ($diff->Items(2)) {
            chomp;
            push @out2, "<Diff>$_</Diff>\n";
        }
        push @out1, "<Diff></Diff>\n";
    }
    else {
        for ($diff->Items(1)) {
            chomp;
            push @out1, "<Diff>$_</Diff>\n";
        }
        for ($diff->Items(2)) {
            chomp;
            push @out2, "<Diff>$_</Diff>\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
@out1:
This is the first line.
<Diff>This line is just appeared in File1.txt.</Diff>
you can see this line in both files.
this line is also appeared in both files.
<Diff>this line and,</Diff>
<Diff>this one are mereged in File2.txt.</Diff>


@out2:
This is the first line.
<Diff></Diff>
you can see this line in both files.
this line is also appeared in both files.
<Diff>this line and, this one are mereged in File2.txt.</Diff>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `diff` from GNU diffutils, you can try the `--old-line-format` and `--new-line-format` options to `diff`.

```
diff --old-line-format "<Diff></Diff>%c'\012'" \
     --new-line-format "<Diff>%l</Diff>%c'\012'" \
     File1.txt File2.txt > NewFile1.txt

diff --old-line-format "<Diff>%l</Diff>%c'\012'" \
     --new-line-format "<Diff></Diff>%c'\012'" \
     File1.txt File2.txt > NewFile2.txt
```

For more details, see the man page; search for "LTYPE-line-format" and "GTYPE-group-format".

Comment: Dear tinita and chepner, thank you for your answers and guides. Both of your solutions work well on my text files, but I think the way chepner threats the files would work more efficient (and reasonably fast on large text files). Thank you again.